# Can't use namespace "Windows.Live"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, live-sdk

I'm new to UWP/Visual/c# in general.
 I'm trying to use the OneNote API for a school project. I came upon this problem when trying to use the Live authentification in visual studio;

I installed the "LiveSDK" reference through nuGet, and it shows up in my solution references, but when I try to include the package in a .cs file with
 "using Windows.Live;"
 I get an error message saying "Live" is not contained in the Windows namespace.

Is adding the LiveSDK as a reference to my solution not enough to use the package?

Comment: You can usually double-click the reference to view the namespaces it contains, have you tried this?

Comment: its not likely supported in UWP.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate further.